# ClassCastException error while loading an UDF in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig latin and trying to implement a UDF but getting following error.

**Error**

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 5, column 28> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: power cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.EvalFunc
Details at logfile: /home/training/pig_1392253062989.log
```

**Script**

```
REGISTER 'hdfs://cloudera-vm:8020/user/training/pig/pow.jar';

base = load 'hdfs://cloudera-vm:8020/user/training/pig/base' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,base:int);

exponent = load 'hdfs://cloudera-vm:8020/user/training/pig/exponents' using 
PigStorage(',') as (id:int,exp:int);

tab = join base by id, exponent by id;

tab2 = foreach tab generate $1 as base, $3 as exp;

fin = foreach tab2 generate power(tab2.$0,tab2.$1);
```

**UDF**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;


public class power extends EvalFunc<Integer>
{

    public Integer exec(Tuple arg0) throws IOException {
        int base = (Integer)arg0.get(0);
        int exponent = (Integer)arg0.get(1);
        int result=1;

        for(int i=1;i<=exponent;i++)
            result=result*base;

        return result;
    }

}
```

**Data Files**

```
Base

1,2    
2,3
3,4    
4,5
5,6
6,7
7,8
8,9
9,10

exponents

1,2
2,3
3,3
4,4
5,2
6,5
7,7
8,4
9,5
```

Comment: Prefix your UDF call with the jar name. pow.power(tab2.$0,tab2.$1)

Comment: Still not working

fin = foreach tab2 generate pow.power(tab2.$0,tab2.$1);


2014-02-12 21:23:57,634 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve pow.power using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /home/training/pig_1392258175870.log

Comment: Have you checked /home/training/pig_1392258175870.log ?

Comment: log file starts with "Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instantiate: pow.power"

Comment: Now I noticed that your UDF JAR is on HDFS. I'm pretty sure that it should be on the local filesystem, not on HDFS.

Comment: Same error ... previously I was successful with registering jars present in HDFS so i think that is not a problem

Comment: which version of pig are you using?

Comment: pig 0.10.0
I am using a cloudera image 4.1 which has centOs and hadoop 2.0.0

Comment: does your jar contain a file called power.class on the top-level?

Comment: yes when i extract the jar file, power.class is present

Comment: well, then it should work. I tested the UDF, works for me. maybe you have an old version of the jar deployed or something?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to compute `tab2.$0 ^ tab2.$1`, you may want to consider using the builtin [POW](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/math/POW.html). Otherwise, if you really want to use your own UDF, I would suggest to put the class in package, use a fully qualified name in your PIG script, and check your classpath. You probably have the wrong class `pow` somewhere in your classpath.

Comment: I did that and put my UDF in a package. while running it is showing no error but when i 'dump' my final output it shows "out of bound" error but illustrate command is working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay problem was in my script commands as i was not passing two inputs that resulted in the error of "out of bounds access while acessing the second field"

REGISTER 'hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/user/training/pig/pow.jar';

base = load 'hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/user/training/pig/base' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,base:int);

exponent = load 'hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/user/training/pig/exponents' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,exp:int);

tab = join base by id, exponent by id;

tab2 = foreach tab generate $1 as base, $3 as exp;

fin = foreach tab2 generate abc.power(base,exp) as res;

dump fin;

**Final Java Code**

`enter code here`

```
package abc;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;


public class power extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

        int base = (Integer)input.get(0);
        int exponent = (Integer)input.get(1);
        double result=1.0;
        Tuple out = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(3);

        for(int i=1;i<=exponent;i++)
                {result=result*base;}
        out.set(0, input.get(0));
        out.set(1, input.get(1));
        out.set(2, result);

        return out;

    }

}
```